# How to append newline character to compact JSONLayout log4j2 entry

Tags: log4j2

I'm using log4j2 to create logs for my Java application.

In the log2j2 properties file I have, among others, the following settings.

```
appender.console.layout.type = JSONLayout
appender.console.layout.charset = UTF-8
appender.console.layout.complete = false
appender.console.layout.compact = true
```

Log lines are logged as follows.

```
{entry0}, {entry1}, ...
```

I would like to log each entry on its own line, separated by a newline character, like this.

```
{entry0}
{entry1}
...
```

How can I make log4j2 separate JSON entries with newline characters, while still maintaining compact mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `eventEol`:

```java
appender.console.layout.eventEol = true
```

According to [the docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSON_Layout):

> **eventEol:** If true, the appender appends an end-of-line after each record. Defaults to false. Use with eventEol=true and compact=true to get one record per line.

Comment: I was inadvertently looking at the 2.1 docs which didn't contain that option. Much appreciated.

Comment: @the_storyteller No problem